# Contracting nested let statments

Tags: coq

At the moment, I have an induction case like this (truncated other info like introduced variables, I can add it back if needed):

```
  IHe : not_set e -> (let (a, _) := sem e c in a) = c
  ============================
   (let (a, _) := let (c0, r) := sem e c in (c0, - r) in a) = c
```

I haven't really used the `let` keyword much (in fact, I used a one-case `match` which Coq seemed to automatically alias to a `let`). However, it seems pretty obvious to me that the statement:

```
(let (a, _) := let (c0, r) := sem e c in (c0, - r) in a)
```

Is just aliasing the same values with multiple levels of indirection. That is, `a=c0=c0` and `_=-r=r`, but I can't figure out how to reduce this. I already tried things like `simpl` and `auto`. I did come across `cbv zeta` which as I understand it should simplify `let` statements, but it didn't do anything.

What am I missing here? I considered introducing a Lemma, but without the ability to contract lets at all I don't know what related thing I'd try to prove. (Meaning: if I could prove anything that would help, I wouldn't need the proof).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the result of `sem e c`.

```
destruct (sem e c) eqn:?. simpl in *.
```

It's also possible to prove

```
(let (a, _) := let (c0, r) := sem e c in (c0, - r) in a) = (let (a, _) := sem e c in a),
```

again by inspecting the pair, since the second element of the pair isn't used.